# Get external content (same domain) and insert it in a special div (no replacement)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two php files (same domain):

```
main.php
test.php
```

Structure of main.php

```
<div class="box">Hello:</div>
```

Structure of test.php

```
<div class="names">
  <span>Andy</span>
  <span>Sandra</span>
</div>
<div class="colors">
  <span>Blue</span>
  <span>Blue</span>
</div>
```

Now I want to insert the content of "names" from the "test.php" inside the "box" div of "main.php" after the content "Hello:".

I try something like:

```
$( ".box" ).load( "http://website.com/test.php .names" );
```

But "load" seems to be replacing content?

So I try $.get:

```
$.get( "http://website.com/test.php .names", function( data ) {
  $( ".box" ).html( data );
});
```

But "$.get" ignores my class name and also "replace" the content completely.

Whats my fail?

Comment: Can you with `id=names` and then use the id in your url ? like `#names`

Comment: @Niladri Same problem with ID ;(

Comment: changed my code with `append` which creates a temporary div to store then content of HTML and then appends it.

Comment: there is an error in your `names` div it has a missing span tag

Comment: All you seem to need is to change to `$( ".box" ).append( data );` in the last code

Comment: @Niladri you are right, I have correct it (was just here a mistake)

Comment: @mplungjan I also tried this way, but a this way I get the "names" div itself too inside the box div ;( - thats also not what will work for me, because I use flex-box and so I only need the content of "names".

Comment: @Pepe I have posted another work around with $.ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the class like below

```
<div class="names">
  <span>Andy</span>
  <span>Sandra</span>
</div>
```

and then use the below script

```
$( ".box" ).append($("<div>").load("http://website.com/test.php .names"));
```

edit : you can do it with ajax also in a different way

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://website.com/test.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        var div = $('.names', $(html));
        $(".box").append(div);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Niladri, I have tried this - same problem - "load" replace all content - so the "Hello:" isn´t any longer available ;(.

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation that specifies ID over class http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @mplungjan i have used class selector

Comment: @mplungjan the OP does not want to remove the existing content

Comment: Right. Missed that part.

Comment: @Pepe did you try with this? the space is required between the  url and selector in .load()

Comment: I´ll try it - give me 2 min ;)

Comment: There was a ")" too much in your code ;). Nice try, but at the end I have an other problem, because ".append" creates a new div ;( and this will not work with my other code or css (like flex-box).

Comment: @Pepe posted another way with $.ajax

Comment: You saved my day - the $.ajax way works!! Thank you!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery append function

https://api.jquery.com/append/

It allows you to append data to the end of the target selector.

Edit: fixed broken link

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ There is nothing in the documentation that specifies ID over class

Answer (score 0):

When you run `$( ".box" ).load( "http://website.com/test.php .names" );` on this HTML `<div class="box">Hello:</div>` you are replacing the content of `<div class="box"></div>` (in this case `Hello:`).  `$( ".box" ).html( data );` is doing the same thing (infact it may be how `load()` is implemented under the hood.  If you want to preseve the content then you can simply capture it before you replace it or possibly alter your html like this:

```
<div class="box">Hello:<span id='Names'></span></div>
```

With a script like this:

```
$("#Names").load("http://website.com/test.php .names");
```